# How to Build GCC For Windows on Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, gcc

I have a VM running CentOs Linux on my Windows 10 machine. Yesterday I built the GCC from source, and saw an option where you could build it to cross compile. My question is this: is it possible (and if it is, how is it done), to compile GCC so that it is capable of building Windows executables on Linux (that I can then run on my computer)? I would like to avoid using MinGW if at all possible so that I won't have to use the special libraries.

Comment: "Special libraries"? Also, just install the proper cross compiler your distro provides.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams yeah you have to use the OpenSSL libraries. Also, what is this "proper cross compiler"? Where can I find it?

Comment: For CentOS it's in EPEL. But it uses MinGW regardless.